# Securely connecting two node.js servers

Tags: security, node.js, amazon-ec2, wkhtmltopdf, nodejitsu

I am hosting an app on Nodejitsu, and I want that app to turn pages to pdf with wkhtmltopdf, which is a binary. Alas I'm not on a big enough plan with Nodejitsu to get ssh access to install wkhtmltopdf.

What I want to do is host the pdf converter on AWS ec2. But I am unsure of a good way to connect the two node.js servers securely. 
Also then when the two servers are connected, what would be the most efficient way to transfer files between these two servers.

Is there concrete design patterns for this?

Comment: Take a look at [secure-pear](https://github.com/substack/secure-peer)

Answer (score 1):

It kind of depends what you need your security for, and how much you need. So I assume you have some data on your nodejitsu server and want to send that (as html) to Amazon, and receive it back (as pdf) from amazon to nodejitsu, and you want:

1. nobody to be able to read your document in between
2. nobody to tamper with your document in between

First, realise that anyone with the right access to nodejitsu or amazon (either an employee or a hacker) will be able to see your data anyways (and probably anyone with access to your database provider as well). The chances for a data leak somewhere there are imho massively larger than someone listening in / tampering on the connection in between (especially if you host both in the US, or (another) country whose government you trust (note that if the US government wants access to your data either the nodejitsu or the amazon servers are physically in the US, they will get it anyways). But, the thing is, barring some major internet disruption, the connection between nodejisu and amazon will not run through shady providers or open wifi networks.

Once you've decided you still want / need the extra layer of security (and complexity), I would say: choose the easy route. No https, no certificates, no asymmetric encryption. Just choose a shared secret (a random password, the longer the better), and just AES encrypt the data before sending it, and at the other end AES decrypt it (using the built in node crypt module). Just send your (encrypted) documents over http, and you're done. You don't even need any authorisation layer: anything received that doesn't encrypt to a valid document, can be discarded.

It is true that https would prevent some other attacks (chiefly that the shared secret probably is somewhere in your code, so also on your local machine (and github) and with asymmetric encryption you only need to store the public key in your code. But still, it will save you a lot of headaches!

Comment: Its not that I want or need a non-normal layer of security. I thought that a simple http request with cors enabled was to easy to be a common design patter for this kind of thing.